# man travels back in time to the rear cockpit of a plane chased by Germans

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

Looking to find a movie I watched as a kid. In the movie close to the beginning, a guy gets teleported back in time to a war to where he finds himself in the rear cockpit of a plane. He shoots the tail end of the plane with the gunners gun. Not sure of the plot, but the actor kinda favored Scott Bakula. He wore a brown leather bomber jacket in the movie as well. Was being chased by some German soldiers. And had a girl with him. I'm thinking time frame of the movie was between 87-95 maybe.

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie and not an episode of Quantum Leap?

Comment: Was it in color? That sounds somewhat similar to a Twilight Zone episode.

Comment: Might also be a good idea to give a range of years during which you were a kid ;)

Answer (score 19):

Could this be "[Biggles: Adventures In Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biggles_(film))" (1986)? as I recall, in an early sequence the hero is transported back to the Western Front of WWI and joins Biggles on a scout mission, as the rear gunner.

[image: Scan of movie poster]

Comment: Huh, that guy really does look like Scott Bakula

Comment: [Jon Anderson - Do You Want To Be A Hero (Biggles Theme)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyLrgbMyT4E) - In terms of cheesy 80s synth soundtrack, you can go further than that. It's so unreal!