# Movie where some soldiers go into a bunker in a city because of dangerous conditions outside

Tags: story-identification, movie

As I was a child I saw a few minutes from a sci-fi movie on a video tape of my parents, but it was so horrifying, that I did not watch it.

The scene I can remember, that people (maybe soldiers) find a kind of bunker in a city. As far as I can remember the city looked like after a (apocalyptic?) war. In the bunker there was one man. In the next scene, somehow the man is outside of the bunker and the others are inside, and they see through the window of the bunker door the other guy dying, as something is happening outside (maybe gas? attack). I am not sure but maybe also a display showed inside the bunker that it is dangerous outside. After that they left the bunker and looked around.

I am not sure at the following (maybe I dreamt it, I do not know): after they left the bunker they checked a main cannon of a tank, and it pulverized in their hands.

I saw the scene before 1993 maybe at the end of the '80. The movie was in color, and was produced in the USA or somewhere else in the west. And I think it was not an episode of a series, but more a movie.

Comment: What is a "a main of a tank"? Like a "gas main"?

Comment: This is probably not so understandable because of my poor english. It was the cannon of the tank -if it was, because I do not remember on that well.

Comment: In the Biggles film, it was a field gun, not a tank. (But don't edit your question.)

Comment: Wow, you did remember this really well!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189602/man-travels-back-in-time-to-the-rear-cockpit-of-a-plane-chased-by-germans

Comment: Well it was 30 years ago (I was about 8), that I saw the scene.  I will check, if this is the movie, but I am pretty sure it is. Thanks for the answer!!!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The scene you described sounds a lot like this movie [*Biggles: Adventures in Time*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090729/) .

The movie wasn't scary at all; it was more of a slightly campy action film. From IMDb:

> Daring British WWI fighter pilot James "Biggles" Bigglesworth and 1980s low-level business executive Jim Ferguson discover that they can time travel to each other's eras. They try to stop the Germans from changing the outcome of WWI.

The scene you describe is when Biggles (and his team) and Ferguson and his bride to be infiltrate a German weapons testing area. They lure or trick the German in the bunker to come out and they run in and lock him out just as the German sound weapon is being tested. The result is that the sound weapon killed the German and made the steel on a small field cannon brittle to the touch. I.e. the barrel of the cannon crumbles in the hero's hand.

Comment: I vaguely remember this movie from my childhood, but reading all the synopsis on it I cant but help think - who is really changing the outcome of WW1 here?  I dont recall the Germans having any knowledge of the "real" outcome (it was just our heroes who were travelling in time), so isnt the sound weapon an original creation in the original timeline and thus its our heroes who were changing the outcome?

Comment: @Moo: Offhand, I don't know... I would have to re-watch the movie

Comment: I don't know how it was edited for you as an American (since you are using the American title) but the scene described involves one of the central characters picking up the arm of a soldier who has melted by the weapon and another character touching the solider's face and bits of his face including his eyeball come out on her hand. So that scene could indeed be called scary.

Comment: @Smartybartfast: for real? I guess they edited that out for us delicate flowers in the US :)

Comment: For real. Normally I'd chuckle at the things that get cut by one country or another but for this film the US was right.  As a film that went to the Family section I don't think it meets the UK PG "moderate violence, without detail, if justified" criterion because that eyeball is definitely detail. I don't think OP will be scared of it today as an adult so, while the US didn't miss anything story wise, the footage is on a popular video website under the US film name if anyone's interested. Just don't blink around the 55 minute mark since it's on screen for a very short time.

Comment: When I saw the OP's description of this movie, I instantly remembered seeing it but didn't know the name - but this fills in the other details (the sound weapon) I remembered.  I don't remember it being overly scary, although seen out of context this particular scene probably was.

Comment: @Smartybartfast +1 to you! Thanks for the info; I never knew that about the movie. Normally, I'm against censorship but that scene would be out of place with respect to the rest of the film and belongs on the cutting room floor.

Comment: @Moo: I remember more about the movie. I don't think it's a "traditional" time travel flick where they change the timeline. Ferguson and Biggles are "time twins" per the movie. When Biggles is in "enough" danger; Ferguson is pulled through time to help him by an unknown force. So, Ferguson always helped Biggles defeat the Nazi's. Ferguson was just the last one to know about it.